# How to format Date(Time)Picker value to a date only string?

Tags: odata, sapui5

My default date setting in Fiori launchpad is `"dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"`. Whenever I get the date from the date picker placed in view, I am getting the date in the above format.

Now I want to send this date to backend through `ODataModel` which generally accepts date in XML date format (e.g. "2014-12-30"). I tried the below code, but it did not work.

```js
var fromDate = this.byId("fromDate").getValue(); // "30.12.2014, 10:36"
var oDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({ pattern : "yyyy-MM-dd" }); // DateFormat required from "sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat"
var subFromDate = oDateFormat.format(new Date(fromDate)); // "0NaN-NaN-NaN".
```

When I check in debugger mode, the value in subFromDate is `"0NaN-NaN-NaN"`. Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add Date / Time from OData Service Correctly to UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593990/how-to-add-date-time-from-odata-service-correctly-to-ui)

Comment: See also [How to convert datetime string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63343915/5846045)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getDateValue()` method instead of `getValue`.

```js
var fromDate = this.byId("fromDate").getDateValue(); // returns a JS date object
var oDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({ pattern : "yyyy-MM-dd" }); // DateFormat required from "sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat"
var subFromDate = oDateFormat.format(fromDate); // "2014-12-30"
```

Answer (score -1):

The **fromDate** isn't correct. When I using **new Date("30.12.2014, 10:36")**, the console show message " Invalid Date".

I look for more information about "Date" from MDN([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)).

**new Date(dateString)**

String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method. The dateString could be '30 12 2014 10:36'.

So you need to replace the '.' and ',' to ' ' in fromDate first.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I formatted date like  '30 12 2014 10:36'. Then applied formatting to make it as '2014-12-30'. Unfortunately, it did not work as expected

Comment: Sorry. The dateString should be 'MM dd yyyy HH:mm', such as '12 30 2014 10:36'. It will work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use display format and value format properties of date time picker.

```
 new sap.m.DateTimePicker("ED",{
                        valueFormat: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
                        displayFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                    });
```

you can easily get the values using

```
sap.ui.getCore().getControl("ED").getValue();
```